# Rails: How to add a sum attribute from polymorphically associated model to retrieved records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I have the following model structure: A Carnival has many Events, which has many Competitors. A competitor has a polymorphic Participant, which is either a Student, or a Team (which has many students). In code:

```
class Carnival < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event_type
  belongs_to :division
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genders
  has_and_belongs_to_many :grades
  has_many :competitors
  has_many :students, through: :competitors, :source => :participant, :source_type => 'Student'
  belongs_to :carnival
end

class Competitor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :participant, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :grade
  belongs_to :house
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :competitor, :as => :participant
  has_one :event, :through => :competitor
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :grade
  belongs_to :house
  belongs_to :gender
  has_many :competitors, :as => :participant
  has_many :events, :through => :competitors
  has_many :carnivals, :through => :events
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end
```

There is a points attribute on Competitor, so that after an Event is run points are assigned to them.

What I would like is a series of methods that would give me all Students along with their total points.

```
Student.with_total_points_for_carnival(c)
Student.with_individual_points_for_carnival(c)
Student.with_team_points_for_carnival(c)
```

I got some SQL that does total points (though I'm a little uncomfortable with how/if it works properly, since I only really stumbled upon it):

```
SELECT 
  name,
  SUM(points) as points
FROM 
  public.students_teams, 
  public.students, 
  public.teams, 
  public.competitors, 
  public.events
WHERE 
  students_teams.team_id = teams.id AND
  students.id = students_teams.student_id AND
  competitors.participant_id = teams.id AND
  events.id = competitors.event_id AND
  carnival_id = 1
GROUP BY
  public.students.id
ORDER BY
  points DESC
```

This gives total points. My Rails attempts give me results, but they aren't correct, and they aren't student records either:

```
def self.with_total_points_for(carnival)
  Student.
    joins(:competitors, :events, teams: { competitor: :event}).
    where('events.carnival_id = ?', [carnival.id]).
    group('students.id').
    sum('competitors.points')
end
```

Any guidance as to how to get this working? So that I could go:

```
<% Student.with_total_points_for(@carnival).each do |s| %>
  <%= s.name %>: <%= s.total_points %> <br>
<% end %>
```

Even better would be a function or scope like `Student.with_all_points_for` which would let me do:

```
<% Student.with_all_points_for(@carnival).each do |s| %>
  <%= s.name %>: <%= s.total_points %> / <%= s.individual_points %> / <%= s.team_points %> <br>
<% end %>
```

but baby-steps for now...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I caught your aim correctly but I think it might help you

Add needed fields to `select`

```
def self.with_total_points_for(carnival)
  Student.
    joins(:competitors, :events, teams: { competitor: :event}).
    where('events.carnival_id = ?', [carnival.id]).
    group('students.id').
    select('students.*, SUM(competitors.points) AS total_points')
end
```

Some notes:

1. (I don't check it but I have similar issue before) if you use Postgres you shouldn't use `students.*` you should list all needed columns directly: `select('students.id, students.name, ..., total_points')`
2. (it can be useful) you can list in `select` any columns from involved tables but remember that you use `group` in the query

PS I am not sure that there is an easy way to get `individual_points` and `team_points` in one simple query. I think you should use subqueries for this purposes and insert them into main query. Be careful because it might be a heavy request to DB and an optimization will be required.